# Typescript issue with 'this' and inner scoped named function

Tags: javascript, typescript

What is the right way to write this?

```
class Test {
    log(data) { ... }
    queryFailed(error) { ... } // Generic error handler
    runQuery(data) {
        doStuff()
        .then(querySuccess)
        .catch(this.queryFailed);

        function querySuccess(data) { // query specific success handler
            this.log("Success!"); // "this" is undefined
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I know I can do it inline like:

```
class Test {
    log(data) { ... }
    queryFailed(error) { ... } // Generic error handler
    runQuery(data) {
        doStuff()
        .then((data) => {
            this.log("Success!"); // 'this' is really '_this' now and set to 'this' right above 'doStuff()' in the compiled javascript
            ...
        })
        .catch(this.queryFailed);

        function querySuccess
    }
}
```

but that clouds up the logic from the result of `doStuff()`

is using .bind(this) inline the right way?

```
class Test {
    log(data) { ... }
    queryFailed(error) { ... } // Generic error handler
    runQuery(data) {
        doStuff()
        .then(querySuccess.bind(this))
        .catch(this.queryFailed);

        function querySuccess(data) { // query specific success handler
            this.log("Success!"); // "this" works
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd just save it to a local variable with an appropriate name. `var test = this;` or something so you know *which* "this" it is, instead of `_this`. I prefer it over `bind()` since it improves the readability of JS callback arrow-code.

Comment: @millimoose Yeah I know I can go that route as well, but it seems like there should be a more TS way to do it (besides using `.bind(this)`). Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like this:

```
class Test {
    log(data) { }
    static queryFailed(error) { } // Make sure we don't try to use 'this' here
    runQuery(data) {
        var querySuccess = data => { // query specific success handler
            this.log("Success!"); // Correct 'this'
        }

        doStuff()
        .then(querySuccess)
        .catch(Test.queryFailed(error));
    }
}
```

Alternatively:

```
class Test {
    log(data) { }
    static queryFailed(error) { }
    querySuccess = (data) => {
        this.log('Success');
    }
    runQuery(data) {
        doStuff()
        .then(this.querySuccess)
        .catch(Test.queryFailed);
    }
}
```

Comment: I need querySuccess to be specific to the parent function though, as it would have specific stuff like assigning variables or whatever. The queryFailed is generic and would just show a failed message or w/e.